# Can you register an OpenSearch URL for a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, opensearch

Is it possible to write a Chrome extension that registers an OpenSearch search handler, which would allow you to tab complete a search in the URL bar and capture the output with your extension? Like the photo below, but hitting Enter would load my chrome extension in a full webpage. I've tried searching the documentation and Google, but did not find any relevant results.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you're asking exactly, but here's the corresponding API: [Omnibox API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox)

It allows you to add your own search, with which you can do as you please from `chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered`, suggest autocompletions, etc.

But there's a requirement of having your own keyword before the search terms.